# Linear dependence of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I saw a lot of questions here, all about vectors. I would like to find out that if the following equations are linearly independent. Can anyone guide me please?

```
$u = t^3 + 4t^2 - 2t + 3$

$v = t^3 + 6t^2 - t + 4$

$w = 3t^3 + 8t^2 - 8t +7 ,\  t\neq 0$

Determine whether $u,\ v$, and $ w$ are linearly independent.
```

@Edit , in our class we trying to find solution like :

```
$k1.u + k2.v + k3.w = 0$
```

Then theese formulas coming :

```
$k1 + k2 + 3k3 = 0$

$4k1 + 6k2 + 8k3 = 0$

$-2k1 - k2 - 8k3 = 0$

$3k1 + 4k2 + 7k3 = 0$
```

is this way wrong ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Wronskian?: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

Comment: @Xoque55 my edit lost, i added our way in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are dependent. because

$$5u-2v-w=0$$

Comment: can we use coefficient matrix to find solution , if yes how ?

Comment: NO, you should use Wronskian

Comment: can you post any example for beginner, i didnt hear it once.

Comment: i've edited my question please can you take a look at ?

Comment: $k_1=5 \, \,k_2=-2\, , k_3=-1$

Comment: thanks , i want to hear that . Can you explain your way how you find k1, k2 ,k3 and i will accept your  answer ? Maybe someone will learn by looking your answer

Comment: We have not unique solution and you can find several other solution.

Comment: okey. but i need to know how you find k1 , k2 , k3 . You said k1=5k2=−2,k3=−1

Comment: $k_1u+k_2v=1.w\implies$ \begin{matrix}
   {{k}_{1}}+{{k}_{2}}=3  \\
   4{{k}_{1}}+6{{k}_{2}}=8  \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: i understand , you giving random value to k3 . Thanks a lot . Have a good day